# .htaccess Error 404

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

When I uploaded my sources to hosting server,  it shows : error 404 Not Found.

In my local server it works perfectly.

Here is my .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/index.php/$1 [L]
```

and my config :

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO";
```

Comment: Probably the docroot is somewhere else? Does any php file work in the directory? Is PHP enabled? Could be anything.

Comment: The Home Page Works Perfectly but Pages of Menus don't Work

Comment: Is your website folder called "folder"?

Comment: Répertoire root>httpdocs

Comment: specificly  root/httpdocs